# Headless CMS for hand coded html website - Moving away from wordpress to headless

Tags: content-management-system, headless-cms

I've handwritten my website html/css/js and I'm looking for a CMS solution that is dead simple to install on a server (possibly something like uploading a folder to my ftp with the CMS in it) and connecting it is roughly a copypaste of tags into h1-h6-p/image areas of the page.
I'm not looking for the most popular solutions (no wordpress, drupal and its friends), I'm looking for something that is easy to setup, easy to connect and most importantly doesnt mess up a nicely working page. I've used wordpress before and I dont like that a page needs to be fixed because wp needs it to be chopped up into parts, which creates a lot of problems on its own - that can be solved with plugins that slow down the site and either work or don't together, etc etc etc, ... its wordpress.

I have looked up headless CMS solutions, and wanted to try a few, but I'm usually stuck at some point:

strapi - requires node js on the server, I need something that can run on any hosting environment without complicated setup

prismic - looks nice, but I'm stuck at the point of how to connect it with a static html website that is not generated by a static site generator (on their integration page theres solutions with  npm, i see no option to connect it to a simple static website)

perch - its pretty close to what I'm looking for but is a pain to install since it needs a bunch of hosting settings that I dont really have access to / or dont really want to mess with

Any ideas?

Comment: Well... just copying is never really the case imho. Usually there is quite a bit of work involved.
Wordpress is fine, if you like it. The nice thing about it is that most of the basics are already set up for you.
Strapi for example is a but different, since you will have to handle all of the routing. Basically you have a totally separate instance just for getting and displaying the data.
If you feel comfortable and know the basics for nodejs it is reasonably simple to setup a basic site with a blog or similar.

I personally really love strapi. Just seems more up to date than wordpress.

Comment: I chose expressionengine, its quite awesome and not as slow as wordpress

Comment: Try Netlify CMS. WordPress is already considered as a legacy web and its plugins have lots of vulnerabilities. I also suggest that you convert your handwritten HTML website to React JS. JQuery is already deprecated and modern websites use the JAM stack architecture.